# How to prove that $(1-x)^n<1-x^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $x$ is a real number greater than zero and less than one, how can we prove that $(1-x)^n$ is less than $(1- x^n)$, where $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Use induction on $n\geq 1$.

Comment: The binomial theorem is also a good place to start.

Comment: On this site, it is generally the case that you are expected to provide context, such as where you came across this problem and what you have tried to solve it.  To avoid having your questions closed and deleted, please see [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that for $x\in(0,1)$ and for any positive integer $n$,
$$(1-x)^{n+1}+x^{n+1}=(1-x)\cdot(1-x)^{n}+x\cdot x^{n}<(1-x)^{n}+x^{n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

No  induction required:  the inequality is equivalent to $\;1-(1-x)^n>x^n$. Now factorise the l.h.s.
$$1-(1-x)^n=x\bigl(1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2+\dots+(1-x)^{n-1}\bigr)>x>x^n$$
since $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for $n\geq 2$, since for $n=1$ both sides are identical.

We can expand $(1-x+x)^n$ to get
$$(1-x+x)^n=(1-x)^n+n(1-x)^{n-1}x+\cdots+x^n.$$
Now every term in the middle of the RHS is positive, so $(1-x+x)^n>(1-x)^n+x^n$ (since $n\geq 2,$ there is at least one middle term). But $(1-x+x)^n=1,$ so the result follows.